# Counting a @State var Double in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to set up the first textfield the same way of the second one but I have some issues! I'm not able to perform a `count` on a Double var like I do on a `String` one.

Do you know why ?

I have tried to use a String interpolation but it didn't work either.

Thanks, in advance.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct FormView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    @State private var value: Double = 0
    @State private var title = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Value", value: $value, formatter: NumberFormatter())
                // .onReceive not possible because of "count" ???

            TextField("Title", text: $title)
                .onReceive(Just(title)) { inputTitle in
                    if inputTitle.count > 48 {
                        title.removeLast()
                    }
                }

            Button(action: {
                if textfieldsNotEmpty() {
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }
            }, label: {
                Text("Confirm")
                    .opacity(textfieldsNotEmpty() ? 1 : 0.5)
            })
            .disabled(!textfieldsNotEmpty())
        }
    }

    private func textfieldsNotEmpty() -> Bool {
        // && value.count >= 1 not possible because of "count" ???
        if title.count >= 1 {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question, what do you want to do in `onReceive`? String is a collection of characters so that is why you can call `count` on it but Double is a value so even if it is made up of a number of digits it doesn't really make sense to use count on it. Anyway, you need to explain what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I would love to count how many "digits" there are on `value` so I can make sure it's not less than 1 (in `textfieldsNotEmpty`) and not more than 8 for exemple (in `onReceive`).

Comment: The problem is that when you are dealing with double values a value like 1 for instance could be represented as 0.999999999… in your variable. It’s much better to check the actual value like > 0 or something. Or use a strings variable instead but maybe that will be more work

Comment: What you need it to check in which interval is you double . Or use log10 of it to compute number of digits. You can also format with %.0f and count the number of char.

Comment: Actually, I've found something : `String(Int(value)).count` is working very well. When the value is set to 0, it's actually 0.00 but the count return 1. But it's not working in my func `textfieldsNotEmpty` because it's not "live" with the textfield. I should maybe use something like onChange?